# Update sample weights in a Keras callback?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, weighted

I am trying to write a custom callback that would update sample weights on the epoch ended. I initialize the custom callback with the original weight but I am not sure how to make sure keras use the new sample weight defined in the callback for fitting the model. Here is a simple example of my code (* 2 is an example and shouldn't do anything in practice).

```
class update_weights(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, sample_weight):
        self.sample_weight = sample_weight

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.sample_weight = self.sample_weight * 2
```

It seems possible to access model parameters from a simple self.model. However I have a hard time accessing the parameters of the fit function. Is it even possible ? Would I be able to modify the parameters of the fit function while calibrating the model ?

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you want to accomplish it is an interesting question.
I guess to find out if the sample weights are actually changing in model.fit (I doubt that it is) you could pick an epoch in on_epoch_end and then set the sample_weight to all zeros for that epoch. Presumably if in fact this changes the value in model.fit when you run the next epoch the resulting loss should be dramatically different. Try something like

```
 def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        is epoch==3:
            self.sample_weight = self.sample_weight * 0
```

On epoch 4 if the sample weights are truly changing I would expect the loss would be zero. Let me know what happens.

Comment: Good idea for a test, unfortunately it shows that it doesn't work.

Comment: when you say doesn't work do you mean the sample weight in model.fit did not change? That is, there was not dramatic effect on the loss?

Comment: The fitting happened normally, whit the loss decreasing gradually, wihtout any significant change around epoch 3-4.

Comment: that is what I expected.  Once model.fit starts to run it just uses the initial sample weight. I don't know of a way to get access to it to change its value. Let me check around.

Comment: From what I read the most straightforward way would be to build the training loop from scratch.

Comment: See : https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/

Comment: yes you need to make a custom training lopp by sub classing the model class.  Here there is an example of how to modify the sample weight. https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/

Comment: YEs this is what I ended up doing. For future readers : customizing the training loop only wouldn't be practical as one would need to rewrite the callback call. Customizing the model is rather straightforward.